# Listing C Constants/Macros

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to make the *GNU C Preprocessor*, cpp (*or some other tool*) list all available macros and their values at a given point in a **C** file?

I'm looking for system-specific macros while porting a program that's already unix savvy and loading a sparse bunch of unix system files.

Just wondering if there's an easier way than going hunting for definitions.

Comment: An interesting question... maybe including your intent will get you a better answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know about a certain spot in a file, but using:

```
$ touch emptyfile
$ cpp -dM emptyfile
```

Dumps all the default ones.  Doing the same for a C file with some `#include` and `#define` lines in it includes all those as well.  I guess you could truncate your file to the spot you care about and then do the same?

From the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cpp.1.html):

> `-dCHARS`
> `CHARS` is a sequence of one or more of the following characters, and must not be preceded by a space.  Other characters are interpreted by the compiler proper, or reserved for future versions of GCC, and so are silently ignored.  If you specify characters whose behavior conflicts, the result is undefined.
>
> > `M`
> > Instead of the normal output, generate a list of `#define` directives for all the macros defined during the execution of the preprocessor, including predefined macros.  This gives you a way of finding out what is predefined in your version of the preprocessor.  Assuming you have no file foo.h, the command
> >
> > ```
> >     touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h
> > ```
> >
> > will show all the predefined macros.
> >
> > If you use `-dM` without the `-E` option, `-dM` is interpreted as a synonym for `-fdump-rtl-mach`.
> >
> > `D`
> > Like `M` except in two respects: it does not include the predefined macros, and it outputs both the `#define` directives and the result of preprocessing.  Both kinds of output go to the standard output file.
> >
> > `N`
> > Like D, but emit only the macro names, not their expansions.
> >
> > `I`
> > Output `#include` directives in addition to the result of preprocessing.

Comment: @Michael, `cpp -dM` without an filename argument waits for data on `stdin`.  You could do that and then type `^D`, but creating an empty file is easier.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that `touch` was an easy way to create an empty file.

Comment: Quickest/easiest way to do this without using dummy file: `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null`

Comment: @Paul R: `cpp -dM /dev/null` works for me... Seems even easier and quicker, at least if considering the typing effort... :-)

Comment: @Paul R - interesting indeed; `gcc` gives `/dev/null: file not recognized: File truncated`. BTW, I was looking at the answer, overlooked that you were actually using `gcc -E` unlike the answer. I was not able to spot any difference with regards to `__STDC__` (`gcc` 4.6.1 for `x86_64`).

Comment: @FooF: I get `__STDC__ = 1` for the cpp method, but it is not defined when I use the gcc/g++ method - this is with gcc/g++ 4.2.1 on OS X.

Comment: @Paul R: `cpp -dM /dev/null | grep __STDC__` --> `#define __STDC__ 1`. This with gcc 4.6.{1,3} Ubuntu Linux. Also for various cross compilers targeting MIPS/ARM + uClibc based on GCC 4.{1.1,2.4,5.0,6.x,7.x}, both cpp and gcc give `#define __STDC__ 1` (3.3.5 did not `#define __STDC__`). Must be some difference in OS X GCC configuration...?

Comment: @FooF: yes, it's probably something to do with the defaults for gcc/g++ in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

With gcc, you can use the "-dD" option to dump all the macro definitions to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Why not consult the section on [Predefined-macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros)? Do you need this for building a project or some such thing?

Comment: Yes *predefined macros* is a good section of the gcc manual, but I'm looking for system-specific macros while porting a program that's already unix savvy and loading a sparse bunch of unix system files.

Just wondering if there was an easier way than going hunting for definitions.

Answer (score 0):

To list "their values at a given point in a C file" using macros, there is two that can demonstrate a given point in a C file, especially when compiled, and would be deemed useful for tracing a point of failure...consider this sample code in a file called *foo.c*:

```
if (!(ptr = malloc(20))){
    fprintf(stderr, "Whoops! Malloc Failed in %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

If that code logic was used several times in this file, and the call to `malloc` was failing, you would get this output:

```
Whoops! Malloc Failed in foo.c at line 25
```

The line number would be different depending on where in the source, that logic is used. This sample serves the purpose in showing where that macro could be used...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros#Commandlineoptions) to a page with an overview of **command-line options to list predefined macros** for most compilers (`gcc`, `clang`...).

Comment: ...and the answer is always "-d" This has been answered 5 years ago, necromancer of the rtfm. I miss the purpose of this answer.